I am writing this smart contract Remix but when I try transferFrom my CELO wallet show me an error
I am using the compiler version of 0.8.19 as it was the one that could run this code. The error I am getting from the wallet connected on the Alfajores Test net is: ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.
Below is my smart contract code and some screenshots. Kindly help me out.
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

interface IERC20Token {
    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract AmemaMicroFinance {
    address internal cUsdTokenAddress = 0x874069Fa1Eb16D44d622F2e0Ca25eeA172369bC1;
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);

    // Function to approve and transfer tokens from sender to recipient
    function approveAndTransferTokens(address recipient, uint256 amount) public payable {
        IERC20Token token = IERC20Token(cUsdTokenAddress);

        // First, approve the contract to spend tokens on behalf of the sender
        bool approvalSuccess = token.approve(address(this), amount);
        require(approvalSuccess, "Approval failed");

        // Check the allowance
        uint256 allowance = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(allowance >= amount, "Insufficient allowance");

        // Perform the transfer
        bool transferSuccess = token.transferFrom(msg.sender, recipient, amount);
        require(transferSuccess, "Transfer failed");

        // Emit events for approval and transfer
        emit Approval(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, recipient, amount);
    }
}

Screenshots:


Looks like you are approving your contract to move tokens from itself. You can't approve your contract to move tokens from msg.sender from within your contract, you need to do that from the msg.sender address at the token which stores the allowance, passing your contract as the spender.


There is no need to make the approveAndTransferTokens function payable so it needs to be remove first as this is a function that allows users to send the cUSDToken to other users.

Before running the approveAndTransferTokens function user will approve the amount by passing the AmemaMicroFinance contract address and the amount need to be sent in the Approve function of the cUSDToken contract.

I just little optimized your code, I didn't faced any error and it's working. you can see the screenshots.


This is the code I used:
First Contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract DummycUSDToken is ERC20, Ownable{
    constructor(address initialOwner)
        ERC20("DummycUSDToken", "CTK")
        Ownable(msg.sender)
    {}

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}

Second Contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "./cUsdToken.sol";

interface IERC20Token {
    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract AmemaMicroFinance {

    DummycUSDToken public cUSDToken;

    constructor(address _tokenAddress) {
        cUSDToken = DummycUSDToken(_tokenAddress);
    }

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);

    // Function to approve and transfer tokens from sender to recipient
    function approveAndTransferTokens(address recipient, uint256 amount) public {

        // First, approve the contract to spend tokens on behalf of the sender
        bool approvalSuccess = cUSDToken.approve(address(this), amount);
        require(approvalSuccess, "Approval failed");

        // Check the allowance
        uint256 allowance = cUSDToken.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(allowance >= amount, "Insufficient allowance");

        // Perform the transfer
        bool transferSuccess = cUSDToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, recipient, amount);
        require(transferSuccess, "Transfer failed");

        // Emit events for approval and transfer
        emit Approval(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, recipient, amount);
    }
}




Hi, thanks for the answer and it work perfectly. But when I use the CELO extension in Remix and the CELO wallet in the browser this code does not work. Because the work I am currently doing requires using Compiler version 0.8.19 and the above mentioned. Thanks.

It will work Try my code, and accept the answer if you found this helpful.
